# NullPointerException when loading typeface from assets in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, android-typeface

I would like to use a custom typeface in my Android app. I followed instructions and created an `assets` folder in Android studio in which I put `verdana.ttf`, as shown on the picture:

[image: assets]

Then I call the following in my `MainActivity` activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Typeface mainFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "verdana.ttf");
```

The code compiles, but when the activity is launched, I get a `NullPointerException` on the above line. I suspected the `verdana.ttf` file might be corrupted, but the error persists when trying different typefaces. Cleaning the project does not help either. Is the assets folder in the wrong location? What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call `createFromAsset()` from an initializer. Please move this to `onCreate()`, after the `super.onCreate()` call.  Methods you inherit in your `Activity` may not work before that point.

Comment: Thanks, it works like that! But under my code construction, I need to call `createFromAsset()` in a static class in an `onCreateView` method. So after the `super.onCreate()` call here, I try `Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "verdana.ttf")` and here again I get a `NullPointerException`. Is there a solution to this (or should I post this as a new question?).

Comment: @Sid: "But under my code construction, I need to call createFromAsset() in a static class in an onCreateView method" -- `onCreateView()` can call `getActivity()` to get a valid `Context` to use. Pass that `Context` into a static method that lazy-initializes your `Typeface`. "Is there a solution to this (or should I post this as a new question?)" -- I do not understand the rest of your comment, so if the advice I give here is insufficient, you may need to ask a fresh question, including the full stack trace and the source code.